# Manipulating txn_id in shopping cart for receiving Paypal IPN

Tags: paypal-ipn

My shopping cart for a ski lessons website works as follows:

- A customer selects dates that they want ski lessons on. Some dates have different prices, for example school holidays and weekends. They submit the selected dates, and the event and its details is provisionally logged in an SQL table with a random transaction ID.
- The shopping cart has also added up the cost of all the selected dates and creates a Paypal Advanced Buy Now Button with the price.
- The customer pays for their selected ski lessons Paypal which sends an IPN back to my IPN listener for verification and to confirm the order.

There's a problem with this though, my IPN script only knows how to verify for a static price, and since every order will have a difference price depending on selection, I need to relate the received IPN to the specific order that was originally placed.

After some poking around I wondered if it is possible to manipulate the `txn_id` to be the same as the random transaction ID set in the first step above.  That way when the IPN report comes back the script will know know exactly which event it is referring to and I can compare the details of that event (e.g. the amount paid compared to the amount calculated_ to the variables returned in the IPN report.

Is it possible to manipulate the `txn_id`, or otherwise send a different identifier with the Paypal button so that I can identify the payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to send the identifier in the "invoice" field, which PayPal will send back in the IPN.